# flask two for loops encode unicode to utf-8

Tags: python, flask

I'm newbie in flask,I want to get mysql data to show in web.But it's unicode,so I try use two for to solve it .But now I want to know the reason why I can use two for loops to encode unicode to utf-8
flask code

```
#coding=utf-8
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'test'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'

mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route('/')
def showbookname():
    cursor = mysql.get_db().cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM manager ")
    bookname = cursor.fetchall()
    return render_template('book.html', bookname = bookname)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run( debug = True)
```

the incorrect HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{{ bookname }}
</body>
</html>
```

the result`((u'Tom',123'), (u'Mark', u'123'))`,my expected result is `((Tom,123),(Mark,123))`

the correct HTML(although I didn't achieve my goal.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{% for items in bookname %}
    {% for item in items %}
{{ item }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

the reasult is `Tom 123 Mark 123` .It's like two `for` loops iterate over the table and `print` all data

Comment: This has nothing to do with unicode, but when you use the `cursor.fetchall()` method it returns a list of tuples. Something like this: `[(..., ...), (..., ...)]`. This is why you need to first iterate through the `list` and then through the `tuple` to get your required values.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation is incorrect unfortunately. The original output is correct - you're printing out the list of rows itself and it's not an unicode issue. That means the rows have to be serialised in some way that's possible to display. In this case that's `((column, column, ...), (column, column, ...), ...)`. It comes from python's `repr(bookname)` and you shouldn't rely on it to look in any specific way. It just happens to show which strings are unicode by prepending the `u`.

If you want the output you expected, you have to construct it yourself:

```
(
{% for items in bookname %}
    (
    {% for item in items %}
        {{ item }}
        {% if not loop.last %}
            ,
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    )
    {% if not loop.last %}
        ,
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
)
```

You'll have to remove the whitespace from the template if you don't want it in the output. But I expect that in reality you want a different output format - you just need to adjust your template for it.

Comment: Thanks you very much,viraptor.